# SslProtocols could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, pocket

Create project pocket use System 3.5.0.0 and add security protocol

> Error: The type or namespace name 'SslProtocols' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: The error suggests that you might be missing some using directives. Specifically `System.Security.Authentication` and `System.Net`

Comment: Did you add [tag:pocket] because you're targeting Pocket pc? I do have to warn you that visual studio 2008, .net framework 3.5 and Pocket pc are no longer supported.

Comment: System.Security.Authentication directives do not exist, System.net has already been added

Comment: @jessehouwing It is the project that they gave me to test, I must make an hhtpWebRequest and the certificate is giving me problems

Comment: Is there any way to perform the WebRequest?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51346252/736079

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework-2-0-sp2-on-windows-vista-sp2-and-server-2008-sp2-1001add1-103f-0a22-e807-00ee2fc7c75d